# Table add one more long column on top and '\multicolumn is obsolete; use \SetCell instead

Tags: tables, tabularray

I am trying to add a table in my work. I drew a red bordered rectangle above to show where I want to place the long column. And then, I am getting those errors, if I address them then the table rendering goes nonsense.

[image]

**My code:**

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}%
    \small
    \begin{table}[H]
        \small
        \centering
        \caption{}\label{tab:blockchains}
        \scalebox{0.97}{
            \begin{tblr}{colspec={l *{5}{X[c,m]}},
                    rows = {font=\linespread{1}\selectfont},
                    row{1} = {},
                    hline{1} = {2-7}{solid},
                    hline{2-7} = {solid},
                    vline{1} = {2-7}{solid},
                    vline{2-7} = {solid}
                }
                \SetCell[c=1]{c,white}
                \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & Platform & Memory & Specification & Price \\
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & Windows & 16GB & Whatever & 10K \\
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & Windows, 32GB & Professional & 22K \\
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & Linux, 64GB & Hacker IBM & 32K \\
        \end{tblr}}
\end{table}}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the multicolumns? Merging one cell into one cell does not seem very useful. Also left aligning an already left aligned column does not seem necessary.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz look at the details again. Look at the screenshot.

Comment: I did look at the screenshot, why do you need the multicolumns in the first column? Please point out which details I am missing.

Comment: I suspect the mesage should bave been "tabulararray does not support \multicolumn" since "obsolete" would imply that it was previously supported.  Either that or that tabular is obsolete (in his opinion).

Comment: @JohnKormylo `tabularray` supported `\mulicolumn` in earlier versions. It was removed with version 2022A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending `\multicolumn` seem unnecessary, simply remove them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}


  \begin{tblr}{colspec={l *{4}{X[c,m]}},
          hline{1-2} = {2-Z}{solid,red},
          hline{3-Z} = {solid},
          vline{1} = {3-Z}{solid},
          vline{2-Z} = {solid},
          vline{2-Z} = {1}{solid,red},
      }
      & \SetCell[c=4]{}\\ 
      & Platform & Memory & Specification & Price \\
      & Windows & 16GB & Whatever & 10K \\
      & Windows, 32GB & Professional & 22K \\
      & Linux, 64GB & Hacker IBM & 32K \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]